# Excel sum how to include minus amount into sum and ignore the rule for minus

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2011, microsoft

Good day I am trying to create a sum on excel so for an example, it is 120000-50000 then with the difference I created another column to say what happened to the 70000.00 so that is perfect but as soon as the first amount is smaller than the second one where I put in numbers to explain the difference it counts it together because the difference now is a minus like 50000-120000 becomes -70000 then I say 70000 was used for this and that en the sum becomes 140000 I did think in using plus in the place of minus but then I will have to go and change every sum per day to accommodate that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Like the community bot mentioned in the comments, it's very difficult to determine what you are asking. Sample data and desired outcome is always helpful. Perhaps you just need to take the Absolute value of your calculations, which will turn the negative to a positive.

So, ABS(5-8) = 3.

Example, cell D2 formula:

```
=ABS(A2-B2)
```

[image]